# Loop through array to get leap years php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm a newbie on php and I need help on how to get a loop such as for or foreach to run an array to then define what year in the array is leap or not leap.

```
 $year = '2012,396,300,2000,1100,1089';
 $y2 = explode(',',$year);
 if (($year % 4 == 0) || ($year % 400 == 0 && $year % 4 != 0)) { 
    echo "True";
 } else{ 
    echo "False"; 
 }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: What you've tried to Loop through array to get leap years?

Comment: Code: $year = '2012,396,300,2000,1100,1089';
$y2 = explode(',',$year);

if (($year % 4 == 0) || ($year % 400 == 0 && $year % 4 != 0))
{
    echo "True";

    }
else{
    echo "False";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 // this will check a year is leap year or not and return true/false
 function check_leap_year($year){
   return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0)));
 }


 $years = '2012,396,300,2000,1100,1089';
 $y2 = explode(',',$years);

 foreach($y2 as $year){
 $test_leap_year = check_leap_year($year);
 if ($test_leap_year) { 
    echo "True";
  } else{ 
    echo "False"; 
 }
 }
```

Comment: Wow that helped alot but, it seems to give some leap years true when it should be false

Comment: yes I know, because I just use your **Leap year finding condition**. I'll update with proper leap year checking condition

Comment: I just noticed that you have $years as $year from the foreach. I changed it but it gives almost the same output

Comment: @EdgarRafael check my answer now and let me know it works for you or not?

Comment: glad it works for you. By the way you can accept it by a green tick mark my answer :) best of luck

Answer (score 0):

put conditions inside loop

```
if((leapyear%4==0 && leapyear%100!==0)||leapyear%400==0)
{
its a leap year
}
```

Comment: $year = '2012,396,300,2000,1100,1089';
$y2 = explode(',',$year);

if (($year % 4 == 0) || ($year % 400 == 0 && $year % 4 != 0))
{
    echo "True";

    }
else{
    echo "False";
}

Comment: Thats the code but I dont know how to get every number or year to output true or false